# How to find double entries and mutate them to a key

Tags: python

My script is this :

```
import csv
with open('lees.csv','rU') as naver:

    reader = csv.DictReader (naver)
    for alist in reader:
        name = alist["naam"]
        polisnumber = alist["polisnr"]
        riskadr = alist["risico adr"]
        insurencecode = alist["branchecode"]
        relationnumber = alist["rel"]
        header = alist["aanhef"]
        tav = alist["tav"]
        thelist = [name,riskadr,polisnumber,
                  relationnumber,insurencecode,header,tav]
```

the output of the script is:

```
['Cautus  B.V.', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa']
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa']
['Cautus  B.V.', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa']
['Cautus  B.V.', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa']
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch']
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch']
['Slever ', 'klopt 42', 'KD2220115', '17', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Slever', 'De heer T.Slever']
```

As you can see I created a dir from a .csv file.

My problem is that I need to make a script to filter the duplicates in `riskadr` (`wei 9-11` / `plein 92` / `tiellaan 42`) and add the `insurencecode` (`AVB`/`BEDR`/`DAS`, etc.) of the second duplicate `riskadr` to the first one in a new list together with the other entry's.

So now we have 2 entry's with the same risk adr like this:

```
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch']
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch']
```

But i want a scipt that makes 1 entry from that 2 entry's with the insurence type added to the first 1 like this(AVB/DAS):

```
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB','DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch']
```

Comment: 4 upvotes?! Do people in the first question queue actually read questions before voting?

Comment: Could you clarify what output you expect?

Comment: 'De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB','DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'] instead of                                                              ['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch']
['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch']

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify it. Also, what if there is more than one duplicate entry? What if your entry ends up with 3 or 4 different insurance codes?

Comment: Well every risk adress(riskadr)needs to get a form with qeustions that match there insurencetypes on that adress.                      A risk adress(riskadr) cannot get 2 BEDR insurences.                  So i need to make a script that mutates the 2 riskadr with 2 types of insurence types to 1 risk adress with the insurences the adress has

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve your goal using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

# define input
l = [['Cautus  B.V.', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'],
     ['Cautus  B.V.', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'AVB', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'],
     ['Cautus  B.V.', 'plein 92', '1129008', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'],
     ['Cautus  B.V.', 'Wei 9-11', '1019123', '10', 'BEDR', 'Geachte mevrouw Daa', 'Mevrouw C.P. Daa'],
     ['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'],
     ['De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'],
     ['Slever ', 'klopt 42', 'KD2220115', '17', 'AVB', 'Geachte heer Slever', 'De heer T.Slever']]

# remove clutter
l_clean = [(x[1], x[4]) for x in l]

# sort (groupby requires input to be sorted)
l_sorted = sorted(l_clean)

# group by first column
l_final = [(k, zip(*v)[1]) for k,v in groupby(l_sorted, key=lambda x:x[0])]

# print output
for k,v in l_final: 
    print k, list(v)
```

The output is:

```
Wei 9-11 ['AVB', 'BEDR']
klopt 42 ['AVB']
plein 92 ['AVB', 'BEDR']
tiellaan 42 ['AVB', 'DAS']
```

Note that you will need to adapt the `key` functions used for sorting and grouping to work as intended with input different from `l_clean`.

Comment: mooeep do i need to add all the entry's in the script because i get a list of 2200 entry's can't i just add the list?

Comment: @user1752643 probably it would make parsing your lists impossible if you'd simply insert other elements in between. You could replace the string `insurencecode` by another list that is able to hold as many `insurencecode`s as you like.

Comment: If i make a function of the import and i return the result (thelist) to the function and then make another function with your script above and add the result in the other function wouldn't it be possible that i won't need to add all the entry's manaully ?

Comment: @user1752643 this is not a forum. Here, you post a question, which hopefully gets answered (in which case you accept an answer). If you have more questions then, first try to solve them yourself, and finally you can post more questions.

Comment: sorry was just happy that some1 finnaly can help me but thx this helped me alot :D

Comment: `sorted(zip(zip(*l)[1], zip(*l)[4]))` -- Really?  That's difficult for me to grok -- Why not do it in 2 steps:  `s_list = sorted(l,key=itemgetter(1,4)); cleaned = [ x[1],x[4] for x in s_list ]` -- I find this to be much more easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [
... ('De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'),
... ('De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch'),
... ]
>>> 
>>> set(a)
set([('De company', 'tiellaan 42', 'KD0022232', '13', 'DAS', 'Geachte heer Tigch', 'De heer I. Tigch')])
>>>
```

save them as tuples already instead of lists, and add them to a set... if this is what you need

Comment: i get a .csv file with 2200 lines of company's i cannot add a single adress. i don't have a problem with double entry's i need to mutate 2 riskadresses into 1 with the 2 insurences the risk adress has

Comment: yes but every year the company's can change so can't u make a more neutral option with python that it automaticly searches for these entry's no matter what the name is ?

Comment: this is the neutralest option you'll ever find... this searches for every duplicate entry in your database and removes the duplicates. Based on your question, your comments above and your comments here, you're asking 3 different things... if you need to eliminate duplicates, this is the fastest option you'll ever find... if you need something more, edit your question and clarify better what you need

Comment: I edited my question with an example hope u get it now (Sorry for my vague english)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something along these lines. Have an in memory array (ultimatelist) in which you check presence of similar thelist. If found append the insurencecode

```
def search(item, array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        # if first four elements and last two elements are identical
        if array[i][:4] == item[0:4] and array[i][-2:] == item[-2:]:
            return i
    return -1

index = search(thelist, ultimatelist):
if index > 0:
    ultimatelist[index] = ultimatelist[index][:4] + thelist[4] + ultimatelist[index][4:]
```